# Sorting an ArrayList using content in the ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, collections

I have a ArrayList "R" which is a collection of objects for the class WordRanking.
WordRanking class has 2 variables in it. 
1.int Frequency
2.String word

Im trying to sort ArrayList R using Frequency

Comment: Have you looked at this method?
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29

Comment: I'm sure with just a minimal amount of research you could come up with at least an attempt to code the sort.

Answer (score 0):

Best way would be to create a custom comparator to define relation between the WordRanking object then using the `Collections.sort(list, comparator);` call.

It should look something like this

```
public class SomeComarator implements Comparator<WordRanking > {
      @Override
      public int compare(ActiveAlarm x, ActiveAlarm y) {
        // return 1 if x>y , -1 if y>x , and 0 if equals
      }
    }

SomeComarator wordComperator = new SomeComarator ();
Collections.sort(R, wordComperator );`
```

On a side note - please don't variable names like 'R'.
And, you know, google.